# How to sort firebase storage bucket by the newest (by date descending)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Can you help me? I'm having trouble sorting files in the Firebase Storage bucket. I knew the list() and listAll() functions will not help me sort, so I tried using timestamps for naming those files. It worked but in ascending order, I'm looking for a way to make the order descending. Thank you.

I tried naming the file with a timestamp but it make the order ascending. I'm expecting descending order (the newest on top).

Comment: How did you order the files in ascending order, on the client? The timestamp that you were using is a long value, a Unix timestamp, right?

Comment: Thankyou for the respond. I'm naming the file when it first upload with timestamp. For example: upload-2022-11-15.png. Then by default when i call list() from firebase storage, the results are in ascending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution for solving this problem would be to store the details for each image in the [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) database. So each image would be represented by a document. So your database structure should look like this:

```
db-root
 |
 --- images (collection)
      |
      --- $imageId (document)
           |
           --- name: "My awesome image"
           |
           --- url: "https://..."
           |
           --- timestamp: November 16, 2022 at 2:46:19 PM UTC+3
```

Now, you only have to perform a query and [specify the direction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data):

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
val query = db.collection("images").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
```

When using this approach, there is no need to provide a timestamp for the time. You can name them whatever you want.

Comment: Thankyou for your respond. I do appreciate your solution. I think it is the best solution exist right now. Thankyou.